# How do I find what library was compiled with lto 4.0 instead of 4.1?

Tags: compiling, gcc, shared-library

All of a sudden I've been getting the following error (something probably updated my gcc or something):

```
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream generated with LTO version 4.0 instead of the expected 4.1
```

However, I'm not exactly sure which library is causing it. How would I find out?

Comment: Same problem here. Linker is giving the error. Just went and cloned a project and trying to build it...  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Followup: Just rebuild all your libraries. I was using OSRM - build clean followed by a rebuild fixed it. So yes I think GCC was recently updated in the past week or so...

Comment: @winwaed what are "all" your libraries?

Comment: I got this error and switched my compiler from `gcc` to `clang`. `export CC=clang; export CCX=clang++; ./configure; make`. Feels like the wrong solution but kind of worked.

Comment: @iso these were the libraries in the osrm make. Over 6 months ago now but i'm pretty certain i didn't have to reinstall anything